# Published Chrome Packaged App

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I created a Chrome Packaged App and already published it. The status is already **published**, but when I go to the [Chrome Webstore](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/apps) and search for my app, I can't see it.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Some points to check on your published App:

- Your app or extension will take few minutes to several hours appear in search result.
- Republish your app
- App indexing to web store takes time/ couple of days
- if all else fails, file a report to [Chromium Support](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/contact/developer_support/?hl=en)

Here is the [Google Group regarding Chromium](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-apps/eQKYm9SQERY%5B1-25%5D) for additional information and you can post the error that you experience there.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i'll mark this answer as soon as it solved my problem.. so up vote for now.. Thanks sir

Comment: Sure, glad to help @JCBorlagdan